# Best C++ way to organaize interaction between class members in base class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

What is the best way to organize interfaction between objects as class members in the base class?
I supposed next structure now (i.e.):

```
class A {
public:
    A(B *b) {_b = b;};
private:
    B *_b;
}

class B {//same way working with C//}

class C {//same way working with A//}

class Outer {
public:
    A a;
    B b;
    C c; 
}
```

I have base class with some objects that could interract with each other (calling functions in other object if it exist). The first idea is storing pointers on all objects that current object should be interracted with. But the question in this approach is: how to track an existing of pointer's object? I suppose objects behaviour something like: "Uh, if this object exists, I will call his member. If not -- no problem, will try next time".

I will be glad if someone could help to improve my understanding of best correct way to do something like this.

Comment: There are too many things wrong in your question to handle. Please read a tutorial first on how to use classes in c++ or a book. I can recommend accelerated c++

Comment: @Rodolfo What things are wrong for example?

Comment: For example in class A you are initializing your pointers in the constructor and not in the list of it. Also base class in OO means a class from which other classes inherit from and in your example well I do not know what you mean. Also your assumption on how the object behave is wrong...

Comment: @Rodolfo Thank you for your reply! Of course it is not inheritence in my short scheme, cause there if no specific line. Just outer class, so I will edit my short code to avoid confusing. And what is about of initializing in the constructor: how it could be initialize in the list, if object could know another object adress only with it constructor?

Comment: What do you mean "existing"? If these objects are all in one base object, they are constructed at the same time and share the same lifetime in most cases.

Comment: @xskxzr yes, I understand and supposed it so. My code is working well, but once I thought that there could be some unexpected situations. Or there is no chance for such behaviour and I can not worrie about watching for objects lifetime in my case?

Comment: One possible case is that the destructor of one subobject is explicitly invoked. But I don't think you should be responsible for such strange cases...